# Libqxt under Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I want to create a tiny app which needs global shortcuts. So, I have downloaded the current version of libqxt (0.5.1) and opened as a project in Qt Creator.

Libqxt compiles without problems in this way, so I thought that adding this in the tab Dependencies of my project it would get added automatically in the build, like Eclipse does with JAR libraries (I know that are different IDEs but it seems to be a common feature among them).

What happens? Qt Creator compiles qxt before my project, when needed, but when I want to include its headers Qt Creator keeps warning me that it cannot find them.

Probably I am missing the correct name of headers (I tried the headers showed in qxt documentation: http://doc.libqxt.org/0.5.0/classQxtGlobalShortcut.html)

By the way, I looked the code for global shortcuts and I think I can rip it out and use it in my app as is and I am going to credit qxt team and open the code of my app.

Comment: Did you add the Qxt include folder to your INCLUDEPATH qmake variable?

Comment: I tried it now, but it doesn't work. I added this in my .pro file:

INCLUDEPATH += ~/tmp/libqxt-0.5.1/deploy/include/

It is a bit disappointing because of things like this that are available in other IDEs. If not, what is the use of the Dependencies tab?

Comment: Well, I think i will left open this question, but I solved my problem installing the lib in the system (make install).

By the way, I changed the path used in my INCLUDEPATH to /home/dario/libqxt-0.5.1/deploy/include/ and it started to find the headers but it fails to compile due to other missing headers used inside.

Comment: Look in your deploy/include dir. Do you see any QxtGlobalShortcut there? In my Windows install the header is located inside the QxtGui folder, so you have to #include "QxtGui/QxtGlobalShortcut".

Comment: Yes, it is located in where you said.

Thanks anyway but while Qt Creator finds the headers, it won't compile with libqxt project. I just installed libqxt and added this on my .pro file:

    CONFIG += console qxt
    QXT += core gui

Now, it works flawlessly and I'm able to build my app. By the way, Qt Creator is a very nice tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qt Creator doesn't know how to expose different libraries to your projects. It's developer's duty. Dependency ensures only that mentioned projects are already built before building your main project.

Your real concern was using Qxt without proper installation. Assuming that `configure` have been run and `libqxt` have been built (using Qt Creator or manually via `qmake`+`make`), my solution is adding following snippet (with obvious QXT_DIR customization) to .pro file:

```
QXT_DIR = $${IN_PWD}/../libqxt-0.5.1
LIBS += -L$${QXT_DIR}/deploy/libs
INCLUDEPATH += $${QXT_DIR}/deploy/include
for(module, QXT) {
 MODNAME = $$upper($$replace(module, "(.).*", "\1"))$$replace(module, "^.", "")
 INCLUDEPATH += $${QXT_DIR}/deploy/include/Qxt$${MODNAME}
 INCLUDEPATH += $${QXT_DIR}/src/$${module}
 win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release):MODNAME = $$join(MODNAME,,,d)
 LIBS += -lQxt$${MODNAME}
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure whether it works in complex projects.

By default Qxt is built in release mode, but Qt Creator uses debug mode and it leads to broken binaries of projects depending on Qxt under Windows. You have to switch your project to release mode or build Qxt in debug mode (run `configure -debug` and rebuild Qxt).

Last thing: In Windows you won't be able to run your project from Qt Creator even if you successfully build it. You must copy needed `Qwt*.dll` files (use the `d`-suffix versions if you're in debug mode) from `libqxt-0.5.1/deploy/libs` to `your_project/(release|debug)` directory .

Comment: +1 thanks for the conf! May I ask you what this line does:  MODNAME = $$upper($$replace(module, "(.).*", "\1"))$$replace(module, "^.", "") . Thanks again!

Comment: @Viet: Qxt uses lowercase for module names provided in `QXT` variable , but CamelCase for library names and some included directories. This is analogous to Qt.

Mentioned line sets `MODNAME` to CamelCase version of `module` using simple functions (`upper()` is undocumented one, self-evident though) and regular expressions.

Comment: @SDX2000 Thanks for noticing. I'll look at it some day.

Comment: @przemoc it's super simple now...almost unbelievable...look at aep's answer.

Comment: @SDX2000 My answer is about using Qxt w/o installation, so `make install` is not an option here. aep is co-author of Qxt, so obviously he knows this stuff. :)

Answer (score 11):

[from the documentation](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/user_guide)

Add the following lines to your .pro file:

```
 CONFIG  += qxt
 QXT     += core gui
```

Note: While building the Qxt on Linux do not forget to do a `sudo make install` otherwise this little piece of magic may fail to work.

Comment: Wow this really works! It seems that the `make install` step modifies some file in the SDK to let it know of its existence. Seems like QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/473/gcc/mkspecs/features/qxt.prf